# How to track usage of this SKU on Google? BigQuery Storage API Network Internet Egress Intercontinental (Excl Oceania and China)(Excl Oceania & China)

Tags: google-bigquery, billing, egress

I need help to understand more about 2 SKU on Google Cloud, I'm charging a big amount on these skus:
BigQuery Storage API Network Internet Egress Intercontinental (Excl Oceania and China)
BigQuery Storage API Network Internet Egress South America to South America

My BigQuery datasets are in US multi-region, I don't understand how I can investigate or get more information about this.

Comment: Can you please [read about why text is better than images of text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541) and then [edit] to add transcriptions of your images of text into actual text? See [/editing-help](/editing-help#code) for how to format code blocks.

Comment: Have you looked in the logs viewer and filtered for that resource? That should show you details...